# How can I make that my ul list is in one line in the nav element?

Tags: css, html

I have the following Code:

```
<nav>

      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

      </ul>   
      <nav>
```

I need every link to be displayed horizontally and not vertically, which css property allow me  to do this?

Thanks

Comment: the `float` css property ( for `ul > li` ).

Comment: Use `float:left` or `display:inline`. and make a habit of googling. :)

Comment: Did you search for "html ul li display horizontally" using your favorite search engine? Because that's exactly the words you used in your question...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Like others have already stated.

Apply a [`float:left`](http://jsfiddle.net/kfYEL/) on the `li`

```
nav ul li{ float:left; }​
```

or [`display: inline;`](http://jsfiddle.net/kfYEL/1/)

```
nav ul li{ display: inline; }​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a demo for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/4C8NP/

```
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 </ul>   
</nav>

body {
 padding:30px;
}

nav {
 overflow:auto;
}

nav ul > li {
 display:inline;
 margin-right:2px;
}

nav ul > li > a {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:10px 20px;
 background:#ccc;
 border:1px solid #666;
}
```